# Gerrit code review plugin for Git Extensions does not let me push

Tags: git, gerrit, git-extensions

I have a gerrit instance setup, where i can push with git, no problem.

The only problem is when I am trying to do the same from Git Extensions.
Then I get this error:

[image]

The .gitreview file is as follows:

```
[gerrit]
host=193.27.84.155
port=29418
project=IMAGO.git
defaultbranch=master
```

On the git-review site I read:

> Required values: host, project
>
> Optional values: port (default: 29418), defaultbranch (default:
>   master), defaultremote (default: gerrit).
>
> Notes
>
> Username is not required because it is requested on first run Unlike
>   git config files, there cannot be any whitespace before the name of
>   the variable. Upon first run, git-review will create a remote for
>   working with Gerrit, if it does not already exist. By default, the
>   remote name is ‘gerrit’, but this can be overridden with the
>   ‘defaultremote’ configuration option. You can specify different values
>   to be used as defaults in ~/.config/git-review/git-review.conf or
>   /etc/git-review/git-review.conf. Git-review will query git credential
>   system for gerrit user/password when authentication failed over
>   http(s). Unlike git, git-review does not persist gerrit user/password
>   in git credential system for security purposes and git credential
>   system configuration stays under user responsibility.

What can I do?

---

EDIT: Ok, so after wandering the internet for quite some time, I decided to go and fetch the latest version of Python and reinstall git-review. Amazingly, this worked. However, now putty is complaining about the private key, connection refused etc. Just to keep everyone updated, if all the work is done via the bash, everything works like a charm. I will get back to my searches and will keep you all posted.

---

EDIT: Well, I have just changed the ssh client to OpenSSH instead of PuTTY and everything works nicely now. If this can help anyone, I am glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following line to the [gerrit] section of the .gitreview file:

```
defaultremote=remote-name
```

By default, remote-name is "origin" but you need to verify what is your Gerrit remote name first:

```
git remote -v
```

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitextensions/o7DEHBP1BsQ) you will find more info about this.

Comment: Actually, no, I don't need to. If you would have read the full post carefully, you would have noticed that it explicitly says the remote will automatically be created if it does not exist.

Comment: And another thing: by default, the default remote name is 'gerrit', not 'origin'

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote "default" I meant default for Git/Gerrit and not for GitExtensions. This difference could be the issue. If you had seen the link I sent , you had noticed that it was exacty this situation.

Comment: I know you meant Git/Gerrit, and I am telling you that the default remote for changes is 'gerrit' not 'origin'. Anyway, I took a look at your link, and it has some relevant info, indeed. Thank you